# Privileges for a Oracle 9i statistics job

Tags: oracle, oracle9i, privileges, job-scheduling, ora-12012

We want to move our automated statistics gathering from an external script into Oracle 9i's job scheduler. It's a very simple job, and the code basically looks like this:

```
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(  
    JOB => <output variable>,  
    WHAT => 'DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DATABASE_STATS(
        cascade => TRUE, options => ''GATHER AUTO'');',  
    NEXT_DATE => <start date>,  
    INTERVAL => 'SYSDATE + 7');
```

The job gets created successfully and runs, but fails with the error:

```
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 25
ORA-20000: Insufficient privileges to analyze an object in Database
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 11015
...
```

The part I don't get is that the user I submitted the job under has the right permissions to gather those database statistics -- if I run the command manually it works. I was curious if Oracle was ignoring any role-based privileges the user had like it does with creating procedures so I directly granted the user ANALYZE ANY, but still no dice.

Are there some other permissions I'd have to directly grant the user to make this work? I'd rather not have to make a separate job for each schema (which does work if I submit the job under the schema's owner).

Comment: What user is this?  One you have created especially for the job?

Comment: This is a user we created, although not specifically for the job. The user is required to do various work in all of our schemas, so it has a custom role that gives it system privileges to do just about everything. That's why I thought Oracle was ignoring role-based privileges, since otherwise the job should have no problems with insufficient access.

Answer (score 0):

What version of 9i are you on. I recall reading on a AskTom thread about 9.2.0.1 having an issue and needing to do a grant select ( i will look up the thread )

Also since you are running DB stats not subroutine ANALYZE ANY DICTIONARY